# How to zoom desktop without Compiz?

Tags: 12.04, compiz, screen, accessibility, zooming

First off I am visually impaired and I have used various Windows-based screen zooming applications.

**Compiz Advanced Desktop Zoom** is fantastic but it totally murders my Wine applications. *Turning off* desktop effects makes them work 100% perfect, but of course I now have no zoom.

So question is, can I zoom without Compiz? Is there any third party application for the job? E.g Qzoom in Windows. I am running Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised to hear that desktop effects have any impact on the functioning of your applications. I wouldn't be surprised to hear that wine flatly ignores your font size settings.

Anyway - [Virtual Magnifying Glass](http://magnifier.sourceforge.net/) and [KMag](http://www.kde.org/applications/utilities/kmag/) look like they will do the job without requiring desktop effects. (the latter can be installed from Ubuntu Software Center)